# Cross-platform device messaging for iOS?

Tags: ios, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to figure out how to send event notifications to a linux box that's behind a router & firewall via an iOS application. Right now, my plan is to use a service like Socket.IO, but they don't seem to have an iOS SDK. So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to accomplish this (passing messages from an iOS device to a node.js application running on a machine inside my home LAN) without using a third-party service like Socket.IO or Firebase?
2. If not, what service would be capable of proxying the communication between the iOS devices and linux box? (Ideally something with both an iOS SDK and an officially supported node package).

Comment: You have to figure out how your two devices are going to connect with each other.  If your Linux server is behind your firewall and you haven't punched any holes in the firewall in order to connect directly to it through the firewall, then you can't connect inbound to it.  The server would have to connect outbound to something.  I don't personally know if you can connect directly to an IOS device from a server (I doubt it) which is why many problems like this use a server in the cloud (pubic accessible) and both devices connect to it.

Comment: I would think your first priority is to figure out the general connection architecture before you go looking for specific libraries to help you.  `socket.io` is just a server and client library - it doesn't have a third party proxy service.

Comment: Whoops, and by socket.io I really mean pusher.com. Derp.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so this was a silly question.

The real issue here is that I needed to break this up into some more digestible subtasks. So instead of trying to solve "pushing events from a mobile device to a box behind a LAN/firewall", I solved:

1. Having the box behind the LAN subscribe to event notifications from somewhere on the public internet. In this case, I'm building a node client app for the linux box that uses websockets to punch through the firewall and open a connection to an endpoint on my server and receive events.
2. Having a way to push events from the iOS application to the public internet. This is pretty easily accomplished with no additional libraries if I have a REST API hosted somewhere that my app can call out to.
3. The third piece is then pretty easy to figure out: I need to have a "server" app somewhere that exposes a REST API that my iOS app can talk to, and then pushes events out to the linux box via a websocket. So I'm probably just going to throw a minimal Express app out there that proxies API calls from the phone to the socket and vice versa. Boom.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to wrap this question up.